# Only displaying section of border on a round image set by border radius

Tags: css

I have an image, made round using `border-radius` and have applied a border to the now round image. I only want to display the border on the top half (or a specific section) of the image.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zigojacko/r8Lpqzz1/) I've mocked up to demonstrate what I am trying to do. As you can see, I'm wanting to not show the border on the image for the section below the horizontal line.

I've played around with various `border` / `border-radius` properties but have not managed to come up with a way I can achieve this - but surely it is possible?

I've included a screenshot of the scenario in context below as well to make it clearer how I'm trying to get this to look.

[image]

### Edit - Workaround Solution

I managed to use [@Alvaro Menéndez's answer](/a/25661242/898933) to come up with a workaround to achieve what I was after (see below screenshot)... It's not the prettiest of solutions though, I was hoping to just be able to control this from pure CSS3 border properties alone.

The code that worked for me was:-

```
.page-header {
  /*max-width: 1260px;*/
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 30px;
  height: 160px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #9c1559;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.page-header:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  height:120px;
  background-color:#fff;
  width:100%;
  bottom:-124px;
  left:0;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your background color is a plain color and not an image I would try to use this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/r8Lpqzz1/1/

it just adds an after pseudoelement to cover the area you need:

```
.nav-primary {
display: block;
margin: 5px;
position:relative;
}
.nav-primary:after {
content:"";
position:absolute;
height:60px;
background-color:#fff;
width:250px;
bottom:-65px;
left:0;
```

Comment: That doesn't work well as it only hides the border below the navigation whereas you can see from the screensphot, that I need to hide it below the bottom of the page-header.

Comment: Just make some absolute positioned colored square div where you want it, over the circle but under the black bar.. it woudn't be difficult (again.. if not background image).. or make a "before" element of the ol with top:-XXpx (margin from header to nav bar)... but the black color of the navbar should be on the "ol" and not in the "li"

Comment: Edited original question with what I used to get it working as per the new screenshot - thanks for your workaround.